# Selective clearing of ehcache entries

Tags: java, ehcache

I'm using Ehcache 3.4 and I have a situation where I need to clear entries from a cache based on their keys. I do not know the keys in advance and I haven't found a clean way to list them from the cache. I read somewhere that listing the keys of a cache is an antipattern and I agree on that, but now I can't see a good way out of this.
Things I've tried or considered:

- Iterate over the cache object (which kinda works, but results in terrible code)
- Keep a secondary list of cached keys
- Asking SO for best practice in this case

I can clear the whole cache, but that results in a performance hit I'd like to avoid. What are my options?

Comment: is the removal condition based on key or any other atribute of the Element ?

Comment: It's based on the key.

Comment: The key describes where in a hierarchy the object resides and I aim at killing only a part of the tree

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what you could do apart from iterating on the entries.

If it wasn't a cache, but let's say a Map, what would you do?

Comment: The main reason for that is that the keys aren't exposed and I had to use reflection to get them. It works, but is not a good solution.

Comment: Again, I don't see what else you can do. Can't you change the design to expose the keys?

Comment: Neither do I. Changing the implementation of ehcache would solve the problem, but I think that would be an overkill.

Comment: No. It won't help. Ehcache would have to do the same iteration internally.

Comment: The iteration itself is not the problem. I just don't like using reflection to access private fields.

Comment: I got that. But if the field is private, it's private. You are in front of a bad design. You need a value that is private. If ehcache was doing it internally, it would use reflection too.